# Higher-Kinded existential type

Tags: scala, existential-type, higher-kinded-types

I've been mulling over a design problem in a library I'm working on, and I realized that using existential types may allow me to change my design in a way that simplifies many parts of my library.  However, I can't quite seem to get it to work.

It seems to me that `myBuilder` conforms to the type `MultiSignalBuilder[E, R] forSome { type E[+X] >: Element[X] }`, where `Element[X]` is `MultiSignalElement[X]`, but the compiler says it does't.  It seems to have to do the fact that E is a higher-kinded type.  Why doesn't this work, and is there a way to fix it?

```
  class MultiSignalElement[+T] {
  }

  abstract class MultiSignal[+T] {
    type Element[+X] <: MultiSignalElement[X]

    val element : Element[T]

    def transform[R[+X] <: MultiSignal[X]](builder : MultiSignalBuilder[E, R] forSome { type E[+X] >: Element[X] }) : R[T] =
      builder.buildNew(element)
  }

  abstract class MultiSignalBuilder[-E[+X] <: MultiSignalElement[X], +R[+X] <: MultiSignal[X]] {
    def buildNew[T](element : E[T]) : R[T]
  }

  object myBuilder extends MultiSignalBuilder[MultiSignalElement, MultiSignal] {
    def buildNew[T](e : MultiSignalElement[T]) = new MultiSignal[T]() {
      type Element[+X] = MultiSignalElement[X]

      val element = e
    }
  }

  val multiSignal = new MultiSignal[Int] {
    type Element[+X] = MultiSignalElement[X]

    val element = new MultiSignalElement()
  }

  multiSignal.transform(myBuilder) //type error on this line
  multiSignal.transform[MultiSignal](myBuilder) //type error on this line
```

Comment: Actually I still could not compile existential-less version with scala 2.11.7

Comment: Could you give a few more details about the motivation behind this piece of code? What exactly is it supposed to achieve? Fixing compile errors without understanding the meaning of the code is quite difficult...

Comment: @Odomontois, Yeah, it looked like it had compiled.  But, in fact the compile errors were just being pre-empted by other errors in the project in other files.  So, I removed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let do step-by-step analysis.

First we have

```
def transform[R](builder : MultiSignalBuilder[E, R] forSome { type E[+X] >: Element[X] }) : Unit = { }
```

Which is equivalent to statement : there exists

```
type E[+X] >: Element[X]
```

For which we can define

```
def transform[E[+X] >: Element[X], R[+_]](builder : MultiSignalBuilder[E, R] ) : Unit = { }
```

Here we have an error

> Error:(7, 18) covariant type X occurs in contravariant position in
>   type [+X] >: MultiSignal.this.Element[X] of type E

This is something. You are expecting your mysterious existential covariant type should be a supertype of another covariant type. I think this is the first thing which is freaking the compiler. Lets change relation to subtyping

```
def transform[E[+X] <: Element[X], R[+_]](builder : MultiSignalBuilder[E, R] ) : Unit = { }
```

Now we have

> Error:(7, 56) type arguments [E,R] do not conform to class
>   MultiSignalBuilder's type parameter bounds [-E[+X] <:
>   MultiSignalElement[X],+R[+X] <: MultiSignal[X]]

So we forgot to require subtyping of `MultiSignal[X]` out of `R` parameter.

Lets change it

```
 def transform[E[+X] <: Element[X], R[+X] <: MultiSignal[X]](builder : MultiSignalBuilder[E, R] ) : Unit = { }
```

Now

```
multiSignal.transform[MultiSignalElement,MultiSignal](myBuilder)
```

Is succesfully compiled.

Finally we could get back to existential version

```
def transform[R[+X] <: MultiSignal[X]](builder : MultiSignalBuilder[E, R] forSome {type E[+X] <: Element[X]}) : Unit = { }
```

With which

```
multiSignal.transform[MultiSignal](myBuilder)
```

Is succesfully compiled.

Sadly

```
multiSignal.transform(myBuilder)
```

Still is not compiled. I think there is too much type relations to resolve for the compiler.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use E[+X] <: Element[X], for reasons you couldn't have know because of the simplifications I made.  See my updated question with the updated code.  I'll play with this and see what I can do, but I may have to rethink this approach.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think I got it fixed.  It came down to the fact that I defined X is covariant in E in the definition for MultiSignalBuilder.  While this is usually true, it's an unnecessary constraint.  Once I removed that, I could also remove the covariance of X on E in transform's type parameter, and it compiles.  Even type inference works correctly.